# Returning ManyToMany field

Tags: python-2.7, django-models

How can I return objects from ManyToMany field? or How can i access authors related to Book?. Thanks in advance. My models.py is

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_Name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Author: ' + self.first_Name + ' ' + self.last_Name

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    author = models.ManyToManyField('Author')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return 'Book: ' + self.title
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly? you need to get the authors from the book or the books from author?

Comment: Can I know both ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `Book` from `Author` by accessing the `book_set`:

```
Author.get(first_Name="Someone").book_set.all() # would return a list of all books
Author.get(first_Name="Someone").book_set.get(...) # would a book
```

Likewise, you can get the authors by accessing the `author` variable of `Book`:

```
Book.get(title="A book").author.all()
```

etc.